# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.SpringTransactionManager.<init>(Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService;)V

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am am starting to learn `spring-data-neo4j`

Very basic test case i am running but unable to succeed. 
the error is: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jRelationshipBacking' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/config/Neo4jAspectConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.aspects.support.relationship.Neo4jRelationshipBacking org.springframework.data.neo4j.aspects.config.Neo4jAspectConfiguration.neo4jRelationshipBacking() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/config/Neo4jAspectConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingInfrastructure' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/config/Neo4jAspectConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.MappingInfrastructureFactoryBean org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.mappingInfrastructure() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/config/Neo4jAspectConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTransactionManager()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.SpringTransactionManager.<init>(Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService;)V
```

`User.java` pojo annotated with `@NodeEntity`

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    User(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

**configuration file is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:spring-configured/>

    <neo4j:config  storeDirectory="D:/data/db"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.neo4j.model"/>
</beans>
```

**JUnit test case is** :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:/graph-test-context.xml"})
public class Neo4jUserTest {

    @Autowired
    Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate;
    @Test
    public void test() {
        User user = new User("test");
        neo4jTemplate.beginTx();
        neo4jTemplate.save(user);
    }
}
```

**i have manually added below jar files from the eclipse buildpath:**

```
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
jta.jar
cglib-2.1.3.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
lucene-core-3.5.0.jar
servlet-api.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
D:\JUnit\junit-4.6.jar
com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
aspectjtools-1.6.0.jar
asm-attrs.jar
asm.jar
spring-data-neo4j-2.1.0.RC1.jar
spring-data-neo4j-aspects-2.1.0.RC1.jar
spring-data-neo4j-cross-store-2.1.0.RC1.jar
spring-data-neo4j-rest-2.1.0.RC1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar
geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
lucene-core-3.5.0.jar
org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jline-0.9.94_1.jar
scala-library-2.9.0-1.jar
server-api-1.7.2.jar
spring-data-commons-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
hamcrest-all-1.3.jar
neo4j-cypher-dsl-1.6.M02.jar
neo4j-cypher-1.9-20120912.103508-32.jar
neo4j-kernel-1.9-20120912.102607-33.jar
neo4j-lucene-index-1.9-20120912.103015-33.jar
```

Comment: I would try a newer version of spring-data-neo4j, like spring-data-neo4j-2.1.0-RELEASE, or even spring-data-neo4j-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Comment: thanks @WernerVesterås can you give me the url to download. I am unable to find it.

Comment: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/2.1.0.RELEASE/ and http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/org/springframework/data/spring-data-neo4j/2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: after adding spring-data-neo4j-2.2.0 am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationExtension this error. please help how to resolve it.

Comment: i updated the question please look once...

Comment: I use Maven to build things. I've created a gist with my dependencies: https://gist.github.com/3976867

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18753/discussion-between-werner-vesteras-and-ramesh-k)

Comment: definately sounds like version incompatibility

Comment: can you suggest me which version is conflicting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it by using below jar files:

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.1.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.12.jar
backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
cglib-2.2.jar
codegen-0.5.5.jar
commons-cli-1.0.jar
ecj-3.7.2.jar
guava-11.0.2.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
hamcrest-library-1.3.jar
jakarta-regexp-1.4.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.1.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
jta.jar
junit-3.8.1.jar
junit-dep-4.10.jar
logback-classic-1.0.6.jar
logback-core-1.0.6.jar
lucene-core-3.5.0.jar
lucene-queries-3.5.0.jar
mysema-commons-lang-0.2.4.jar
neo4j-1.8.jar
neo4j-cypher-1.8.jar
neo4j-cypher-dsl-1.8.jar
neo4j-graph-algo-1.8.jar
neo4j-graph-matching-1.8.jar
neo4j-jmx-1.8.jar
neo4j-kernel-1.8.jar
neo4j-lucene-index-1.8.jar
neo4j-udc-1.8.jar
plexus-compiler-api-1.9.1.jar
plexus-compiler-javac-1.9.1.jar
plexus-compiler-manager-1.9.1.jar
plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
plexus-utils-3.0.jar
querydsl-apt-2.8.2.jar
querydsl-codegen-2.8.2.jar
querydsl-core-2.8.2.jar
querydsl-lucene-2.8.2.jar
scala-library-2.9.1-1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar
spring-aop-3.2.0.M2.jar
spring-aspects-3.2.0.M2.jar
spring-beans-3.2.0.M2.jar
spring-context-3.2.0.M2.jar
spring-core-3.2.0.M2.jar
spring-data-commons-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-neo4j-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.0.M2.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.0.M2.jar
spring-orm-3.2.0.M2.jar
spring-test-3.2.0.M2.jar
spring-tx-3.2.0.M2.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

Comment: Cool. Feel like writing up a blog on how you set it up without Maven? Might be useful for others.

Comment: @Ramesh K How did you be able to download spring-data-neo4j 2.1.0 RELEASE since it doesn't exist yet?   only 2.1.0.BUILD-SNPASHOT exists

Comment: @Mik378 http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.data/spring-data-neo4j/2.1.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 2):

As Peter said, the problem is you are including a different version of the Neo4J library than Spring is expecting.  A **NoSuchMethodError** means a client is calling a method that doesn't exist.  This couldn't happen if you include the version Spring is using becuase Spring would have got a compile error if they called a method that doesn't exist.

How are you building you project?  Please provide more detail like a POM if its a maven project.

**Update:** The ***org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.SpringTransactionManager*** comes from your Neo4J installation not the jars you are supplying.  What version of Neo4J are you running?  It needs to match the version that spring-data-neo4j is expecting.

Comment: i have updated the question with jar files which i have used please check once...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using an old Neo4j version. Could you try with the coresponding Neo4j version, I think 1.8 instead of 1.7.2?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even i tried with the neo4j 1.9 also. Still getting the same error...

Comment: another way to make sure you are getting the correct versions is to use Maven for dependency resolution. Could you clone and execute https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples/hello-worlds and see if that works?